# Validar formulário - Step by Step (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo um formulário com base nesse template: https://colorlib.com/etc/bwiz/colorlib-wizard-22/index.html

Porém preciso que a validação seja feita para os campos! Não se pode ir para o próximo STEP até essa validação.

Não estou encontrando solução para esse tipo de formulário, de que forma validar?

Acredito que seja no JS abaixo onde faz a chamada onStepChanging. Porém toda alteração que tentei, a passagem para o próximo step não funcionou.

```
    $("#form-total").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        autoFocus: true,
        transitionEffectSpeed: 700,
        titleTemplate : '<span class="title">#title#</span>',
        labels: {
            previous : 'Voltar',
            next : 'Próximo',
            finish : 'Enviar',
            current : ''
        },
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
            var fullname = $('#first_name').val() + ' ' + $('#last_name').val();
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var date = $('#date').val();
            var time = $('#time').val();

            $('#fullname-val').text(fullname);
            $('#phone-val').text(phone);
            $('#email-val').text(email);
            $('#nota-val').text('Sua no foi '+nota+'!');
            $('#date-val').text(date);
            $('#time-val').text(time);

            return true;
}
    });
```

Comment: Onde está a documentação? O que o suporte disse a respeito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No evento `onStepChanging` faça a sua validação e caso não esteja de acordo utilize um `return false`

```
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
        var fullname = $('#first_name').val() + ' ' + $('#last_name').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var date = $('#date').val();
        var time = $('#time').val();

        //Exemplo
        if(phone == ''){
           alert("O telefone não foi preenchido!");
           return false;
        }

        $('#fullname-val').text(fullname);
        $('#phone-val').text(phone);
        $('#email-val').text(email);
        $('#nota-val').text('Sua no foi '+nota+'!');
        $('#date-val').text(date);
        $('#time-val').text(time);

        return true;
    }
```

Mas o que eu de fato recomendaria é ler a documentação do componente que está implementando e utilizar o `jquery.validate` junto.

[JQuery-Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form)

Answer (score 0):

Basta você usar `required` na **tag** Obs.: Só funciona nos `inputs`... Veja mais em ... https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

Comment: Nesse caso não funcionaria, porque sem o validate o required só seria verificado no submit final do form e olhando os hiddens `$("[nome]-val")`